# SQL Server Configuration Manager is missing in the V18.5

Tags: sql-server, ssas, configurationmanager

I tried everything from the link - https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2019/03/01/sql-server-sql-server-configuration-manager-missing-from-start-menu/

But none of those files are present in my laptop.

In the SSAS, When I clicked Browse I got this error 'A connection cannot be made. Ensure that the server is running'
Hence I looked for the configuration manager in my laptop and its missing. Can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server Configuration Manager is installed in the Windows SysWow64 folder as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-configuration-manager). You can simply double-click on the file to run the snap-in.

```
+------------------------+--------------------------------------------+
| SQL Server 2019        | C:\Windows\SysWOW64\SQLServerManager15.msc |
| SQL Server 2017        | C:\Windows\SysWOW64\SQLServerManager14.msc |
| SQL Server 2016        | C:\Windows\SysWOW64\SQLServerManager13.msc |
| SQL Server 2014 (12.x) | C:\Windows\SysWOW64\SQLServerManager12.msc |
| SQL Server 2012 (11.x) | C:\Windows\SysWOW64\SQLServerManager11.msc |
+------------------------+--------------------------------------------+
```